# How to open Excel file from Flutter mobile app using some other app, e.g. Google Sheets?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have generated an Excel file that I would like to open with some other app that user have installed on a mobile device, e.g. Google Sheets, Microsoft Excel, Numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved this issue with the plugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/open_file_plus